# Saving and Loading Preferences, Android 4

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

I am trying to save and load preferences of an Android app, but I cannot seem to get it working correctly. All tutorials I have come across have almost identical code as I. The save code in the app is:

```
// s is a prepared string
// nameVal is the preference identifier
SharedPreferences pref = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                  pref.edit().putString(nameVal, s).commit();
```

and the load code (into an ArrayList) is:

```
a = ((SharedPreferences) getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE)).getString(fileName, "").split("\n");
```

There is no preference-specific exception to add, it just does not store and retrieves "". Does anybody have experience with this?

Comment: what issue you are facing ?

Comment: Are you sure that nameVal equals to fileName ?

Comment: There is not error, but the string either 1), does not save to the preferences at all; or 2), does not load them.

Comment: Fedepaol, Yes. I changed fileName to nameVal in this post (it was originally a file operation). Both variables are fileName in the source

Comment: The string I am attempting to save is large (2500 one-word lines), could that be doing it?

Comment: @ScottHermanson : see [this](http://saigeethamn.blogspot.in/2009/10/shared-preferences-android-developer.html) tutorial for saving or retrieving value in shared-preferences

Comment: @ScottHermanson : i just suggest this link because it's working fine for me . and first issue is value is not storing or retrieving from  shared-preferences so i think first we solve this issue after that other

Comment: I read that tutorial last night, but I will give it another look since it is working for you. I will write back with clarification or a solution.

Comment: Hello Everybody, I have a hunch that my prompt dialog (from which the identifier is gathered) is the culprit. I am going to integrate everything and see how it works. If it works, I will upload the solution to help anybody else who has a similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was easy - Android dialogs do not pause the main thread (I did not know this). I added in a static edittext and the preferences loaded perfectly...well, not perfectly, but the rest is due to parsing. If you have come to this site with a similar problem, take out the prompt dialog and add in an edittext.

Thanks again!